# Need to change the partition column to another column and reloading the data into new partitions

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to change the already existing partition column to another column.

The current workflow I'm using:

1. Backup the existing data
2. Create a new table with new partition column
3. Reload the data into new partitions

My problem:
Since there is huge data in our existing partition tables, this way will be costly

Is there a way we can do Alter table and change partition column name to another?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not avoid 1-time cost of scanning the table as you can see from the error message generated from this CREATE OR REPLACE DML command

```
#standardSQL
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.table`
 PARTITION BY DATE(ts)
 AS 
 SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

> Cannot replace a table with a different partitioning spec. Instead, DROP the table, and then recreate it. New partitioning spec is interval(type:day,field:ts) and existing spec is none

What you can do to save cost is use the `WHERE` command to limit the number of the partition you move from existing table to the new table

```
CREATE TABLE project.mydataset.newPartitionTable
 PARTITION BY date
 OPTIONS (
   partition_expiration_days=365,
   description="Table with a new partition"
 ) AS
 SELECT * from `project.dataset.table` WHERE
 PARTITIONTIME >= '2019-01-23 00:00:00'
 AND _PARTITIONTIME <= '2019-01-23 00:00:00'
```

You can consider for example not to move your Long-term storage which is data you haven't access for the last 90 days (see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage) for more details)

[image]

If you want to keep your original table name you can drop/create it with the new partition field, after the copy, and use the copy option from webUI which will be free of charge

[image]

Comment: Hi Neha0908 hope this answer helped you and If so please consider accepting and voting up as this is important to the community

Comment: any chance we can alter partition without charge